# Login Failed for user 'reader' (SSMS)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, view, permissions, ssms-2017

I created a login called `reader` in my SQL Server and granted `SELECT` permissions to it for my database schema. After I logged in with the SQL Server authentication using the `reader` credentials, I tried executing a `SELECT` statement on a table and it worked perfectly.

However, when I try to select the `TOP(1000)` rows of a view, I get an error "Msg 18456 - Login failed for user 'reader'".

Can someone tell me what the problem is please?

Comment: Trying to `SELECT` from a `VIEW` won't generate that error. That type of error is generated when you attempt to connect to an instance.

Comment: @Larnu I am executing the following query: 'SELECT TOP (1000) *
  FROM ['database_name'].['schema'].['View_Name']' and the Msg 18456 is unfortunately being generated.

Comment: @Znigii, perhaps SSMS is attempting to (re)connect when you run the query. Are you running the second query from the same window?

Comment: @DanGuzman Yes, I am executing the query from the same window. However, I found it really strange since another view from another database schema which I granted permission for the 'reader' is executed successfully.

Comment: I **assume** that the view isn't in a different database.  The fact that you are using the database in the name implies this. If you just use 2 part naming, does it work? Does the `VIEW` reference objects on other databases/servers?

Comment: @Larnu Yes, the view has a reference from another database but I already granted SELECT permissions in the other database.

Comment: Perhaps you could post the SQL you ran to grant the user the permissions, and the DDL of your view. Otherwise, I'm afraid, there's little we can do to help as you've effectively given us a black box you want us to fix, and we can't look inside the box.

Comment: Can it be that you say "another database" but it's another SERVER? "Login failed" means you was trying to connect to server, but if you are already connected this means you use linked server and try to connect to it. It seems thay your view uses some objects from linked server

Comment: This is my through train as well @sepupic; why it would be real useful to see the DDL and the statements the OP ran right now. :)